# filter rows where a column string starts with a specific word in R? ""^word" doesnt work

Tags: r

list of USA movies filtered by columns

```
    dfUSARating <- dfUSAMovies[, c("rowNum","title", "genre", "rating", "vote")]
```

pulling rows genre contains Thriller

```
    thrill <- dfUSARating %>% filter(str_detect(dfUSARating$genre, "Thriller"))
    head(dfUSARating$genre, n=3) 
    [1] ['Documentary', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Fantasy', 'Mystery', 
    'Sci-Fi']
    [2] ['Comedy', 'Horror', 'Sci-Fi']                                    
    [3] ['Biography', 'Drama', 'Sport']
```

There a repeats of genres, I want to filter the genre if it starts with Thriller only, not if the string contains thriller. Movies have multiple genres and am getting repeats.

```
     dput(head(dfUSARating))
    structure(list(rowNum = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 15L), genre = 
    structure(c(869L, 
    752L, 638L, 130L, 229L, 910L), .Label = c("['Action', 
    'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy']", 
    "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Biography', 'Drama', 'History', 
    'War']", 
    "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Biography', 'Drama', 'History']", " 
     ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Biography', 'History', 'Romance']", 
    "['Action', 'Adventure', 'Biography', 'History']", "['Action', 
    'Adventure', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Drama', 'Thriller']", 
    "['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Mystery']", "['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 
    'Fantasy']", 
    "['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Sci-Fi']", "['Comedy', 'Drama', 
    'Romance', 'Sport']", 
    "['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Thriller']", "['Comedy', 
    'Drama', 'Romance', 'War']", 
    "['Comedy', 'Drama', 'Romance', 'Western']", "['Comedy', 'Drama']",  
    "['Western']"), class = "factor"), rating = c(5.3, 4.5, 7.8, 
     4.8, 7.1, 7.6)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You seem to have strings containing JSON data so your string won't start with "Thriller", it will start with "['Thriller". So try `filter(str_detect(genre, "\\['Thriller"))` (the slashes are needed because the bracket is a special regular expression character). Are you sure you copied your dput currently? If I paste that into R there seem to be clear problems with quoting so I can't really test the code. Also does your sample data actually contain any rows that start with Thriller? It doesn't look like anything would match.

Comment: Yes it does, just took beginning and end of dput, it was too long to paste it all.  I just noticed the mistake will edit.  Try that.

Comment: That worked, Thank you MrFlick! much appreciated.